# Send ajax 2 times

Tags: jquery, ajax

Can anyone see my code. I think, ajax send my data two times, that's why in my db duplicate records

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function isValidEmailAddress(email) {
        var regex = /^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i;
        return regex.test(email);
    }

    function check() {
        var registration = $('input');
        registration.removeClass('error').removeClass('valid');
        var error = 0;
        registration.each(function () {
            var value = $(this).val();
            if (value.length < 4 || value === null) {
                $(this).addClass('error').animate({ opacity: 0.5}, 500);
                error++;
            } else {
                $(this).addClass('valid');
            }
        });
        if (!error) {
            if ($('#password').val() != $('#conf_password').val()) {
                $('input[type=password]').each(function () {
                    $(this).removeClass('valid').addClass('error');
                });
            }
            var email = $('input[type=email]').val();
            if (email.length < 1 || email.value == null && !isValidEmailAddress(email)) {
                $(this).addClass('error');
                error++;
            }
            else {
                $(this).addClass('valid');
            }
        }
    }

    function send_form() {
        check();
        var data = $('#registration').serialize();
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "{{ path('registrationAction') }}",
                data: data,
                dataType : 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    if(data.success == true){
                        window.location.replace("{{ path('loginAction') }}");
                    }
                    else
                        alert("Error");
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    $(function () {
        $('#submit_form').click(function () {
            send_form();
        });
    });
</script>
```

And one more question , my form is sent in any case, although it should not. How can I do so that if there are errors , the form does not send

I may be missed something ? Please, help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not prevent normal form submission while submitting it via AJAX. Also, it is better to bind form submission to your form `submit` event, rather than your submit button `click`, because forms are also submitted for example on `Enter` keypress. You need to do the following:

```
$(function () {
    $('#form-name').submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        send_form();
    });
});
```

Comment: @Etarnal Thank you for answer. But now, after registration i don't redirect to loginAction? What could it be?

Comment: There could be several reasons for this - try logging what your ajax request returns. Also, you should provide a callback for `error`, in case your script does not return a valid json response.

Comment: I found the reason . I have to check on the existence of php $_GET , but it does not send ajax in my code . Maybe you know how to get parameter using jquery?

Comment: It is empty because you're using `POST` as your request type. You need to check `$_POST` array for data.

Answer (score 0):

In the form submit event give return false or else your form gets submitted post your ajax.

```
$(function () {
    $('#submit_form').click(function () {
        send_form();
       return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Have a global variable

```
var req_sent = 0;
```

before ajax request put

```
if(req_sent == 1){
return;
}
req_sent = 1;
```

in success and error callbacks of ajax set

```
req_sent = 0
```

Have a validator method called on form submit

```
<form onsubmit="checkIfValid()">....
```

This method should return false if form is not valid. Your form will not be submitted.